# Create table in html using C# object list

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, webforms

I have created an API that returns in json a list of type EventJOINEventDate. I am now trying to write a web form that calls the API and shows the Events from the json file in a table. The web form has 2 inputs: input_date and input_num. 
I wrote this far but am now stuck and don't know how to proceed. How do I use what I wrote to create an html table?

```
    string StartDate = input_date.ToString();
    string Num = input_num.ToString();
    string url = String.Format("Http://..."); //I have my url here
    WebRequest requestObj = WebRequest.Create(url);
    requestObj.Method = "GET";
    HttpWebResponse responseObj = null;
    responseObj = (HttpWebResponse)requestObj.GetResponse();
    string strresult = null;
    using (Stream stream = responseObj.GetResponseStream())
    {
        StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(stream);
        strresult = sr.ReadToEnd();
        sr.Close();
    }
    var serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
    List<EventJOINEventDate> EventList = (List <EventJOINEventDate>)serializer.Deserialize(strresult, typeof(List<EventJOINEventDate>));
    foreach(EventJOINEventDate obj in EventList)
    {
        long EventID = obj.EventID;
        DateTime StartDateTime = obj.StartDateTime;
        string EventName = obj.EventName;
        string EventDesc = obj.EventDesc;
        string Address1 = obj.Address1;
        string Address2 = obj.Address2;
        string City = obj.City;
        string State = obj.State;
        string Zip = obj.Zip;
        string EventURL = obj.EventURL;
        string RegistrationURL = obj.RegistrationURL;
        string InvitationURL = obj.InvitationURL;
    }
```

Comment: There are a lot of options.  Do you have the HTML table (Repeater, DataGrid, etc..) already set up to to bind? Or are you wanting to create a new dynamic table via code-behind and render it out?

Comment: @JohnPete22 I haven't set anything up yet, and what I want is exactly what you said, to create a new dynamic table via code-behind and render it out.

Comment: Sounds like a lot of overhead to render server-side instead of just using a client side framework to consume the API and do the rendering. After all that's usually the point of having an API returning JSON.

Comment: @Filburt what would be the best way then to display in a table in html the json file that was retrieved from the API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, here is a quick solution for you.  As another posted, client-side might be more efficient.  But if you want to go server-side, you can take this approach and tailor it, add some styling to the Table/Rows/Cells.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="_testPWforSO.aspx.cs" Inherits="_testPWforSO" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <div>
            <asp:PlaceHolder ID="phTest" runat="server" />
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

```
using System;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class EventList
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string EventName { get; set; }
    // more variables
}

public partial class _testPWforSO :  System.Web.UI.Page
{

    public void Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        EventList test = new EventList() { Id = 12, EventName = "test123" };
        EventList test1 = new EventList() { Id = 34, EventName = "test456" };
        List<EventList> events = new List<EventList>() { test, test1 };
        TestFunction(events);
    }

    public void TestFunction(List<EventList> events)
    {
        HtmlTable table = new HtmlTable();

        // add table headers if you want

        foreach (EventList item in events)
        {
            table.Rows.Add(AddRow(item));
        }

        phTest.Controls.Add(table);
    }

    public HtmlTableRow AddRow(EventList item)
    {
        HtmlTableRow result = new HtmlTableRow();

        result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.EventName });
        result.Cells.Add(new HtmlTableCell() { InnerText = item.Id.ToString() });

        return result;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Disclaimer:** *This answer tries to propose a different approach than the server-side / code-behind solution. It is meant as an alternative to illustrate ways to consume an API.*

Using jquery, all you need is a static html page and few lines of js.

Since you didn't show the exact structure of your JSON, you will have to adjust according to your JSON properties.

```
<html>
<head/>
<body>

    <div>
        <table id="events" />
    </div>

    <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jQuery/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var uri = 'your/url/here';

    $(document).ready(function () {
      // Send an AJAX request
      $.getJSON(uri)
          .done(function (data) {
            // On success, 'data' contains your json result.

          // Look for your column names
          var cols = Object.keys(data[0]);

          // create the table header
          var header = $('<thead />').appendTo('#events');

          for (var i = 0; i < cols.length; i++) {
              $('<th />', { text: cols[i] }).appendTo(header);
          }

          // create the table body
          var tBody = $('<tbody />').appendTo('#events');

          // create rows and cells
          for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) { // each row

              var row = $('<tr />').appendTo(tBody);

              for (var j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) { // each column

                  var obj = data[i];

                  $('<td />', {
                      text: obj[cols[j]]
                  }).attr('data-label', cols[j]).appendTo(row);
              }
          }
          });
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Of course this is just raw table output. For adding more style you surely will want to use an existing jquery table plugin or a framework like Angular or Knockout.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with javascript. Make an ajax call to this method. In the response, you will get a Json. 
1.) Convert it to an object in Javascript : - https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp

Let us suppose that you got an array of objects
2.) Run a foreach loop [Loop 1] through array. Create a data row in this loop. : - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_table_insertrow.asp

3.) Run a foreach loop [Loop 2] for each object in the array (Nested foreach inside [Loop 1] ). Create a table column and add the value of that column through javascript : - https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_tablerow_insertcell.asp

This should do it. Let me know if this solves it